# Getting column does not exist error when trying to connect with Postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

i have five columns in table in postgres db

SELECT "widgetId", spaceurl, section, signingkey
FROM gitbook.helpdocs;

where "widgetId" is primarykey

entity class:

```
@Id 
@Column(name = "widgetId")
String widgetId;

@Column(name = "spaceurl")
String spaceurl;

@Column(name = "section")
String section;

@Column(name = "signingkey")
String signingkey;
```

but it is giving me error:

ERROR: **column h1_0.widget_id does not exist**
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "h1_0.widgetId"

I am giving the correct column name but still getting this mismatch error
I have tried with many options like addingg generation type and changing the case of the text. but
nothing working

Comment: Advice: Never ever use UPPER case in your database object names, like table and column names.

Comment: A typo: `widgetid` vs. `widget_id`.